# How can i remove the filter to multiple excel files with visual basic?

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have around 500 files of excel and the most part have filter. Now i need to put all information in one sheet. I found how to put all in one sheet but the books with filter only copy information with filter and i need all.

So, i need to remove filter of all excel files. Important (not all files have filter)

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want help with a VBA macro to do this you'll need to show the effort you've put in to accomplish your goal and where it's not working. Please read [How to Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive more effective help on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Before you copy the data, you should use:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
```

This will turn off the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Will remove any filter on all opened workbooks, have fun :)

```
sub try_this()
dim wb as workbook
dim sh as worksheet

for each wb in workbooks
   for each sh in wb.worksheets
      sh.AutoFilterMode = False
   next
next

end sub
```